# Is there a way to tell if my composable is 'exposed' in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Let's say we have n specific composables on the screen.

```
data class MyItem()

@Composable
fun MyComposable(myItem:Item, onExpose:() -> Unit) {
   Box {
      //blabla.... If any part of the Composable is exposed, it should call onExpose.
   }  
}

@Composable
fun MyComposableList() {
   // or LazyColumn, Anyway.
   Column {
       MyComposable(Item()) { println("Item 1 Exposed!!") }
       MyComposable(Item()) { println("Item 2 Exposed!!") }
       MyComposable(Item()) { println("Item 3 Exposed!!") }
       .....
       MyComposable(Item()) { println("Item 4 Exposed!!") }
   }
}
```

These items depend on various variables such as the size of the terminal and the combination of other composables,

All of them may be exposed at once, or only the top few may be exposed.

I know that ScrollState lets you 'roughly' know how many items are visible through the current scroll.

But I'd like to know if Composable can know by itself that it's being exposed to the screen.

Is this a feature supported by Compose? Or is this the part where I have to use ScrollState?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can not exactly know if the composables are exposed (or I think you want to say drawn), let me explain.

First of all, in compose, any composable on the same level of the composition tree can be re-composed or exposed or drawn at any time in any order as much as they need. For example, you can add a SideEffect or LaunchedEffect composable with any print statement inside your MyItem along with the onExpose method and try on different devices or emulators and you will see different order of print statements possibly on each run. However, you can use LazyDSL informations such as the state of LazyColumn in order to get the visible item information. This is in my opinion the best way to access the drawn info in your case and I use it in that way in my projects.

On the other hand, like the given example, you can use a SideEffect composable inside MyItem and it will eventually run when the MyItem exposed, maybe before exposed, maybe after exposed, or at the same time of exposition. But in the end, MyItem will eventually drawn to the screen and SideEffect composable will eventually run and hence you can use onExposed and make your composable "exposition-aware". Basically, this is how I implemented "seen instagram story" like feature.